# Block height and notification procedure for v7+ forks

Tags: hard-fork, fork-notification

Has the block height for the v7 fork been decided upon yet? What procedure will be used to provide notice exchanges, mining pools and merchants about the upcoming fork.

Starting with v7 will their be any wallet based notification systems for upcoming forks?

Comment: I don't think this has been decided upon yet. Still stuff to iron out regarding bulletproofs and 'mobile friendly' tweaks first I guess..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has the block height for the v7 fork been decided upon yet?

As can be seen from the [code here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp#L91-L109), there's currently no block height set yet for the v7 fork. It'll likely be somewhere in March 2018 though. However, there has also been some talk about pushing it back 1-2 months to accommodate more review for single-output [Bulletproofs](https://getmonero.org/2017/12/07/Monero-Compatible-Bulletproofs.html).

> What procedure will be used to provide notice exchanges, mining pools and merchants about the upcoming fork.

Typically the core-team and the community will try to make exchanges, merchants, services, mining pools, miners, and (economically sensitive) nodes aware of the upcoming hard fork. This is done by spreading awareness of the hard fork on social media, sending out emails, or by other means of contact. In addition, I typically put up a hard fork megathread (example [[1]](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6yuv2s/psa_users_solominers_exchangesmerchantsservices/), [[2]](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/62dyel/psa_users_solominers_exchangesmerchants_and_pool/)). These threads basically inform users and asks the community to spread awareness of the hard fork.

> Starting with v7 will their be any wallet based notification systems for upcoming forks?

A few weeks before the fork, the daemon will start notifying the user of an upcoming hard fork. In addition, if the user hasn't upgraded after the fork, the daemon will notify the user that there's a new version available.